# AppExchange CRUD FLS for task object

Tags: apex, appexchange, restresource

When I apply CRUD FLS to submit my code for code scanner my class business logic is not working even though I have given all access to task and activity object.

Class is rest resource class and is accessible from site.
Following is the block of code where I am applying CRUD FLS:-

```
String contactId = {!recordId};
if(Schema.sObjectType.Task.fields.whoId.isCreateable()){
     Task t1 = new Task();
     t1.whoId = contactId;
}
if(Task.sObjectType.getDescribe().isCreateable()){
     insert t1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring your task object inside if block

```
if(Schema.sObjectType.Task.fields.whoId.isCreateable()){
     Task t1 = new Task();
     t1.whoId = contactId;
}
```

It will not be available when compiler will move ahead to execute this block

```
if(Task.sObjectType.getDescribe().isCreateable()){
     insert t1;
}
```

it will give you error `Variable does not exist: t1`

**How did it even allow you to Save your class ? I am surprised**

you need to declare `Task t1 = new Task();` outside if block so that **t1** will be accessible here

```
if(Task.sObjectType.getDescribe().isCreateable()){
         insert t1;
}
```

Comment: Even if apply CRUD on task fields and access are provided then also not working and returning false in IF.
Is this the right way to do?


`for (Task objTask : taskList){
           if(Schema.SObjectType.Task.fields.Message_Status__c.isAccessible() || Schema.sObjectType.Task.fields.Message_Status__c.isUpdateable())
                        objTask.Message_Status__c = taskStatus;
             }
 }`